# Allow user to resize datagridview from the right only - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Windows Form program where I've added a tabControl. One of its tabs contains a combo box that holds names of some items. I also have a DataGridView below that presents to me a record. 
The thing is I want to make this GridView resizable by the user when the program is run from only its right side and no other sides. I think it is possible but I am not sure how this will work. 
https://gyazo.com/34e9d13b3858b57a614fe4ac29346c37 Here's a GIF of what I wanted but, this was in design. 
Thank you.